# How to Send and Receive ByteA Images with PostgreSQL, node-pg and ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, express, node-pg-pool

This is my `images` table in PostgreSQL:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS images (
    ----------------------------------------------------
    id  UUID        NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
    ----------------------------------------------------
    pic BYTEA       NOT NULL,
    ext VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    ----------------------------------------------------
    CONSTRAINT     images_pk
       PRIMARY KEY (id)
    ----------------------------------------------------
);

-- Inserting Fake Data

SELECT set_config(
    'default_pic_path',
    '/path/to/image.png',
    FALSE
);

INSERT INTO
    mi.images (
        pic,
        ext
    )
VALUES
    ------------------------------
    (
        bytea('default_pic_path'),
        'png'
    );
    ------------------------------
```

And I would like to have an endpoint for adding images to the DB and also another for retrieving them, sending them back with the proper image extension (e.g. `.png`, `.jpg`, etc.).

What is the recommended way of doing this in ExpressJS with `node-pg`?

So far, I've found tons of ways of doing this converting images to text, but that's highly inefficient... I've also found some solutions in which we turn the returned `node-pg` `Buffer` into a local file and then use `res.sendFile(...)`, but that is also highly inefficient. Is there a better way?

Anyways, here's a sketch of an endpoint for getting an image (in TypeScript), with the local creation of a file I had criticized:

```
import { Request, Response } from "express";

export async function getImage(req: Request, res: Response) {
  try {
    const mainPool = new Pool({
      user: "postgres",
      password: "password",
      database: "main",
      host: "localhost",
      port: 5432,
    });

    const results = await mainPool.query(/* sql */ `
      SELECT pic, ext
      FROM   images
    `);

    const pic = results.rows.[0].pic as Buffer;
    const extension = results.rows.[0].ext as string;

    const filename = `default_pic.${extension}`;
    const filepath = join(
      __dirname,
      "../path/to/assets/folder/",
      `assets/${filename}`
    );

    // Doesn't really write the file properly, 
    // probably some error with encoding...
    writeFileSync(filepath, pic);

    res.sendFile(filepath);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a small sample. It's Javascript instead of Typescript. But it will make it clear anyways.

It uses a slightly modified schema:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS images (
    id           UUID        NOT NULL DEFAULT gen_random_uuid(),
    image        BYTEA       NOT NULL,
    content_type VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT   images_pk   PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

The main difference is that a content type instead of a file extension is used.

To insert images using SQL, the Postgres server needs to have access to the images. And you need to have the permissions to execute `pg_read_binary_file()`:

```sql
INSERT INTO images (image, content_type)
VALUES (pg_read_binary_file('/var/images/rose.jpg'), 'image/jpeg');

INSERT INTO images (image, content_type)
VALUES (pg_read_binary_file('/var/images/banana.jpg'), 'image/jpeg');
```

The sample also assumes that a HTML file called `upload.html` is in a directory called `public`. It displays the UI for the file upload.

**upload.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Image upload</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>

  <p>Image Upload</p>
  <form action="/upload" method="post" encType="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="image" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
  </form>
  
</body>

</html>
```

The node.js/express part is quite compact. It assumes the following *npm* packages are installed:

- `express`
- `pg`
- `express-fileupload`

To view an image, go to `http://localhost:3000/img/cef95cc8-137a-4a06-9d0d-ccee0cb018be` (replacing the UUID with the id of the image you want to view).

To upload an image, go to `http://localhost:3000/upload.html`

```js
const { Pool } = require('pg')
const pool = new Pool();

const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');

app.use(express.static('public'))
app.use(fileUpload());

app.get('/img/:id', async (req, res) => {
    const result = await pool.query(
      'SELECT * FROM images WHERE id = $1', 
      [req.params.id]
    )
    res.set('Content-Type', result.rows[0].content_type)
    res.send(result.rows[0].image)
})

app.post('/upload', async (req, res) => {
    const result = await pool.query(
      'INSERT INTO images (image, content_type) VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING id', 
      [req.files.image.data, req.files.image.mimetype]
    )
    res.redirect(`/img/${result.rows[0].id}`)
})

const port = 3000
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Postgres app listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

The sample makes use of the fact that *express-fileupload* makes the uploaded file available as a `Buffer`. And the Postgres client accepts a `Buffer` for inserting the image data. It also returns a `Buffer` when querying the `image` column. And `res.send()` also accepts a `Buffer`.

Since the `Buffer` instance are held in memory, this approach is efficient. But the maximum image size is limited by memory.

**Update**

It the image should be uploaded using Javascript, minor modifications are needed. It still assumes that the image has been selected in a user interface using an input element of type `file`.

**Additional server-side code**

```js
app.post('/upload2', async (req, res) => {
  const result = await pool.query('INSERT INTO images (image, content_type) VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING id', [req.files.image.data, req.files.image.mimetype])
  res.json({
    imageId: result.rows[0].id,
    imageURL: `/img/${result.rows[0].id}`
  })
})
```

If the upload is successful, this endpoint returns JSON data instead of redirecting to the image URL.

**upload2.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Image upload</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>

  <p>Image Upload</p>
  <p>
    <input id="file" name="image" type="file" />
    <button id="upload-js">Upload JS</button>
  </p>
  <p><a id="image-link" href="#"></a></p>
  
</body>

<script>
  const fileInput = document.getElementById('file');
  const uploadButton = document.getElementById('upload-js');
  const imageLink = document.getElementById('image-link');

  uploadButton.addEventListener('click', async () => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('image', fileInput.files[0]);
    try {
      const response = await fetch('/upload2', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData
      });
      
      const imageMetaData = await response.json();
      imageLink.href = imageMetaData.imageURL;
      imageLink.innerHTML = 'Uploaded Image';

    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  });
</script>

</html>
```

If the image is uploaded successfully, a link appears with the image URL. The URL was returned by the REST endpoint.

Comment: Thanks a lot! In your upload endpoint, is there a way of using template strings instead? I wonder how it would work, if it's possible, given that the image that is of type `Buffer`...

Comment: I don't think you can do it with the *pg* Postgres client. With naive template strings you lose parameter binding (and the associated performance) and break non-trivial data types like buffers. But it looks as if [Postgres.js](https://github.com/porsager/postgres) provides tagged template functionality achieving it.

Comment: Is there a way of uploading the image and other data with the JS `fetch` API?

Comment: Thanks! Just found out you can also do `const form = document.querySelector('form'); const formData = new FormData(form)`, and then you basically don't need to use `.append`, it's all automatically done.